# ConnectionManager: pool of connection

Tags: java, jdbc

i have a jdbc client that communicate with a postgresql database by contact a RMI server. In this rmi server i have a simple ConnectionManager code:

```
public class ConnectionManager {
    private ConnectionManager(){};

    private static boolean driverLoad = false;
    private static final String pgDriver="org.postgresql.Driver";
    private static final String pgUrl = dbc:postgresql://localhost:5434/franchising_db";
    private static final String user = "postgres";
    private static final String pass = "password";

    public static Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        if(!driverLoad) {

            Class.forName(pgDriver);
            driverLoad = true;
        }
        return DriverManager.getConnection(pgUrl, user, pass);
    }
}
```

Now postgresql has a limit of 30 contemporary connection, but this kind of ConnectionManager does not avoid this use case. I would like to create a defined number of connection (for example 5) and when a client call getConnection method, if a connection is available, return it, then if all connections are busy, client wait for the first free connection.
How should i modify that code for do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look into the jdbc connection pooling where you can specify the number of open connections, idle time, wait time etc. The most popular libraries are [C3P0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) and [DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/)